# returning a generic class

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I must admit, I don't get this error:

```
public <S extends A> Class<S> foo(){
    return A.class;
}
```

Will result in a "incompatible types"-error.

```
Expected: Class<S>
Found: Class<A>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot return a CLASS! You should return some context or an object

Comment: @Apurva yes you can. But for this to work with returning `Class<A>` the method should declare it returns `Class<? extends A>`.